# What is nowadays called silazane?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, nomenclature, organosilicon-compounds

[image]

**Example from the Recommendations 2013.** *Left*: Alleged disilazane ; *Right*: My version

[image]

**Clearer example without obvious flaws in alternative structure.** *Left*: Alleged disilazane ; *Right*: My version

I am confused with the contemporary IUPAC nomenclature of organic compounds. According to Recommendations 93 (available at acdlabs.com), silazanes are heterogeneous hydrides where both terminal atoms are silicon atoms ([R-5.1.4.2](https://www.acdlabs.com/iupac/nomenclature/93/r93_353.htm)). The same can be concluded from the general rule on heterogeneous hydrides ([R-2.2.3.2](https://www.acdlabs.com/iupac/nomenclature/93/r93_198.htm)). However, in the introductory chapter of Recommendations 2013 (which is [freely available](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/chapter/9781849733069-00001/978-1-84973-306-9) at RSC Publishing site) on page 82 the compound given in the image is given two names, with the least priority (non-PIN) variant being 1,1′-(2-ethenyl-1,2,3-trimethyldisilazane-1,3-diyl)bis(ethan-1-one). I am confused by this name, as, by rule R-2.2.3.2, terminal atoms should be lowest in the Hantzsch–Widman order, which preserves unambiguity of the structure. From this rule, I expect disilazane to be something like the structure on the second image (although I acknowledge that the tetravalent nitrogen must be positively charged, which changes the name automatically).

**TL;DR** So the question is:

> Do Recommendations 2013 change something about naming heterogeneous hydrides? And if so, what is now called silazanes?

Comment: With view on both the wikipedia entry (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silazane) and by a commercial supplier (https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/chemistry/chemistry-products.html?TablePage=16245452) I would like to hint that the second formula features a tetravalent N the aforementioned examples (and the first example by you) do not.  I _thought_ «disila» then indicates the presence of «two atoms of silicon» as in the right hand example and HMDS (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bis(trimethylsilyl)amine) though.

Comment: I know about the tetravalent N, I addressed it in the question. I will add another pair of structures for my point to be clearer; it is just that this is example from the Nomenclature book.

Comment: The Recommendations 2013 are not bug-free, in fact: see, for example, the 2nd structure on page 75.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems this name should not be in the blue book. It is an error.

The following instruction is what [Corrections to *Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry. IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013*](https://www.qmul.ac.uk/sbcs/iupac/bibliog/BBerrors.html) has given for your problem:

> Page 82, P-15.3.2.4.1, example 4 on this page.
>   Delete 1,1′-(2-ethenyl-1,2,3-trimethyldisilazane-1,3-diyl)bis(ethan-1-one).

As Igors Mihailovs (OP) pointed out in comment section to the question, the Recommendations 2013 are not error-free. You may see how nany errors have been corrected in this web page. For example, page 75 has 4 errors in that page alone!

Comment: That error list on the web page struck me like a lightning bolt :-0

Comment: I actually had another subquestion about that structur, as to why there is locant 1 cited in the "ethane-1-one", but multiple corrections on the page You cited confirmed this is ANOTHER bug in this name.